# Problem with Firebase Push Notifications in Ionic Cordova project

Tags: firebase, cordova, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I am developing an Ionic app and I need push notifications. I am using firebase Cloud Messaging but i'm facing some errors with @ionic-native/push packet.

This is my initPushNotification() called in my app.component.ts

```
initPushNotification() {
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: 'MY_SENDER_ID'
      },
      ios: {
          alert: 'true',
          badge: true,
          sound: 'false'
      }
   }

   const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


   pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

   pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

   pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

I'm currently facing this error:

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>      at PushObject.on (index.js:61)
>      at MyApp.webpackJsonp.493.MyApp.initPushNotification (app.component.ts:105)
>      at app.component.ts:75
>      at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>      at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
>      at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>      at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
>      at polyfills.js:3
>      at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>      at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
>      at c (polyfills.js:3)
>      at polyfills.js:3
>      at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>      at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
>      at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>      at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
>      at o (polyfills.js:3)
>      at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
>      at p (polyfills.js:2)
>      at HTMLDocument.v (polyfills.js:2)
>   defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1449

I get this error in Chrome, in emulator and in real device.

It seems that pushobject is not being recognized.

Note that I am using:

```
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';
```

And that I have imported Push as Provider in app.module.ts.

Thank you guys if you understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you have different versions of @ionic-native packages installed.

Run an `npm ls  --depth=0` and make sure that all your @ionic-native packages installed locally are well aligned

Answer (score 1):

Fixed just using previous version of push.